# Is possible to connect to RDS Oracle DB instance with SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, ssh, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect into my mac with the endpoint that AWS give me but i can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to database instance in RDS by using the endpoint and the credentials associated with the rds instance

Refer the below link for guidance:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.Oracle.html

Also ensure that the security group associated with the RDS instance has appropriate port open for oracle connection.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, You can.

These are the AmazonRDS settings.

[image: AWS RDS settings]

and this is the SQL Developer connection window

[image]

database host name should be the AWS endpoint & SID should be the AWS DB Name.